# MVC3 renderbody issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having a small issue some razor tests, that I'm doing with RenderBody in MVC3.

This is my view:

```
@model List<IAdviceContent>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Site.cshtml";
}
<div>
@{
    foreach (IAdviceContent item in @Model)
    {
       <p>hello</p>
    }
}
</div>
```

In the master page i just have:

```
<div id="Container">
   <div id="Header"></div>
   <div class="VerticalBlankSeparator"></div>
   <div id="Content">
   @{
       RenderBody();
    }
   </div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm having is, that the view is rendered without printing "hello", but the foreach is executed 5 times.

Do you know, what I'm missing in the master or in the view?

Comment: What is the HTML output?

Comment: This is the HTML output

<div id="Container">
   <div id="Header"></div>
   <div class="VerticalBlankSeparator"></div>
   <div id="Content">
   
   </div>
</div>

Thanks.
Greets.
Josema.

Comment: <div id="Content"> </div> : So the MasterPage->RenderBody() returns nothing? (otherwise we would see the <div></div> tag from your view.)

Comment: Exacly. I dont know why the renderbody is not working...

Comment: What is the name of your view? Are you browsing to the correct view? 
It seems like the view is not called at all. (according to the HTML output)

Comment: Okay aparently you cannot use @{} with renderbody. I just use @RenderBody() and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you do `@RenderBody()` instead of `@{ RenderBody(); }` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Renderbody should not be called as you're calling it as it won't output anything to the stream. Change it to just plain `@RenderBody()` and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@RenderBody();` as `@RenderBody()`. Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

use `@RenderBody()` instead of :

```
@{
       RenderBody();
    }
```

and it will work fine